# How to relate jQuery to field in table?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I’m not sure if I’m asking my question in the best way possible or being totally clear but I’ll do my best.

I have the field `$quantity` in my `Quantity` entity. Then in one of my controllers I create an instance of my class entity `Quantity` like this: `$quantity = new Quantity();`. Finally I set the quantity like this: `$quantity->setQuantity(1);` just so things make sense and my app can run.

Then in my twig file I implement the jQuery number spinner (https://jqueryui.com/spinner/). I place the `quantity field` (1) in as the value.

Then in my script for the spinner I try to make it so when I click up or down the quantity is consequently updated in the database. I FAIL. This is what I need help with.

Ultimately I want to update the total cost of the users cart depending on the quantity of the products in the cart.

`ProductController relevant functions`:

```
/** 
 * Creates the option to 'add product to cart'.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/addToCart", name="product_addToCart")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function addToCartAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $product = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->find($id);
        $product->getId();
        $product->getName();
        $product->getPrice();
    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);
    // $quantity = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['id' => $this->getUser()]);

    if ($this->checkUserLogin()) {
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Login to Create a Cart');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('product');
    }

    // --------------------- assign added products to userCart id ------------------------ //

    $quantity = new Quantity();

    if (is_null($cart) || $cart->getSubmitted(true)) {
        $cart = new UserCart();
    }

    $cart->setTimestamp(new \DateTime()); // Set Time Product was Added 
    $quantity->setQuantity(1);   // Set Quantity Purchased.......Make jQuery # Spinner the input of setQuantity()
    $cart->setSubmitted(false); // Set Submitted
    $cart->setUser($this->getUser());  // Sets the User ONCE
    $cart->addQuantity($quantity);    //  Add Quantity ONCE
    $quantity->setUserCart($cart);   //   Create a UserCart ONCE
    $quantity->setProduct($product); // Sets the Product to Quantity Association ONCE
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->persist($cart);
    $em->persist($quantity); 
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' has been added to the cart!');


return $this->redirectToRoute('product');

}

/**
 * Shows Empty Cart
 * 
 * @Route("/showCart", name="product_showCart")
 * @METHOD("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showCartAction(Request $request) {

// --------------------------- show only what the user added to their cart --------------------------- //

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($this->checkUserLogin()) {
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Login to Create a Cart');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('product');
    }

    // $product = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->f

    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);

    // $productsInUsersCart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['product' => $cart->getId()]);
    // dump($productsInUsersCart); die;
    // dump($cart); die;

    if (!$cart) {
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'There is NO CART');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('product');
    }

    $sub = $cart->getSubmitted();

    /**
     * Function in UserCart that Maps to Quantity where product values lives.
     *       $quantity is an object (ArrayCollection / PersistentCollection)
     */
    if ($sub == false) {
        $quantity = $cart->getQuantities();
    } else {
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Cart should be EMPTY');
    }

    if (!$cart) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'ERROR: You got past Gondor with an EMPTY CART'
        );
    }

    $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0;

    $totalCostOfAllProducts = $this->getTotalCost($cart, $totalCostOfAllProducts);

    if (empty($price) && empty($quantity) && empty($totalCostOfAllProducts)) {
        $price = 0; $quantity = 0; $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0;
    }

    return array(
        'user' => $cart->getUser(),         // for :UserCart
        'cart' => $cart,
        'quantity' => $cart->getQuantities(),         // for :UserCart
        // 'quantity' => $quantity,         // for :UserCart
        'totalCostOfAllProducts'    => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
    );
}
```

`twig file where jQuery spinner script is` (and the only thing that works is the jQuery spinner increasing or decreasing numbers...nothing else):

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1 class="text-center"><u><i>Your Cart</i></u></h1>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="who_is_logged_in">
            {% if user is null %}
                <a href="{{ path ('fos_user_security_login') }}">Login</a>
            {% else %}
                <u>Hello<strong> {{ user }}</strong></u>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price Per Unit</th>    
                    <th>Remove Product</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {% for key, product in quantity %}  
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ product.product }}</td> <!--Product-->
                        <td>
                            <input class="spinner" value="{{ product.quantity }}" style="width:30px">
                        </td> <!--Quantity-->
                        <td>${{ product.product.price|default('') }}</td> <!--Price-->   
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ path('product_remove', {'id': product.product.id }) }}">
                                <button name="REMOVE" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeButton">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </td><!--Remove--> 
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}      
            </tbody>
        </table> <!--top table-->

            <div class="money-container">
                <p class="text-right">Total Cost: ${{ totalCostOfAllProducts }}</p>
            </div> <!--moneyContainer-->

        {% for flash_message in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
            <div class="flash-notice">
                <strong>{{ flash_message }}</strong>
            </div> <!--flashNotice-->
        {% endfor %}

    </div> <!--container-->


    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('product') }}">
                Add More Products
            </a>
        </li>

    {#    {% if cartArray is empty %}   #}
    {#    {% else %}                    #}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('product_bought') }}">
                    Buy These Products
                </a>
            </li>
    {#  {% endif %}                     #}

    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".spinner").spinner();
    $('input.spinner').on('change', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('product_showCart') }}',
            method: 'POST',
            data : {
                quantity: $this.val()
            }
        }).done(function(resp){
            console.log('success', resp);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log('error', resp);
        });
    });
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

[image: showCart screenshot]

[image: quantity table screenshot]

If you can't already tell I'm new to jQuery/web development but I'm learning day by day. I could really use some help/guidance!

EDIT:

I changed my script to this and now I see my messages in my console but still nothing gets updated/changed in the database and when I refresh my page, the quantity goes back to display '1'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".spinner").spinner();
    $('input.spinner').on('spinstop', function(){
        console.log('spinner changed');
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('product_showCart') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data : {
                quantity: $this.val()
            }
        }).done(function(resp){
            console.log('success', resp);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log('error', resp);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could  you be more clear on what exactly is going wrong? You state that YOU FAIL when it comes to updating the quantity, though it is unclear as to what is actually failing. Are you getting any errors? Are you getting wrong input to your server action? Where does the problem lie?

Comment: The problem is that if I try to increase or decrease the number in the spinner, I want that new number (quantity) to be in the database for the product in the users cart. I want the '1' in the above table to be updated to whatever number I change it to using the spinner. I hope that's more clear

Comment: Like I said, I know what you WANT. I don't know where in the process of accomplishing this it's going wrong. When looking at your code I see the ajax request, the php action and all the good stuff, though we cannot see right away where the error lays. You need to tell us which part of updating the value is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get any errors. If I use the spinner, the number go up and down but nothing is sent to the database/updated. If I refresh the page with the new quantity it goes back to '1' @Glubus does that make sense?

Comment: Ah now we're getting somewhere. So, have you checked whether or not the request is actually being sent? Use the console in your browser to check  this (press F12 when you're on the page and go to the console tab before you send the request). If you don't see anything, or if your request gets a 404 response, you know your issue lays with your  Javascript. If you get another response, you can say your problem lays with your serverside code.

Comment: I get absolutely nothing in the console log so it must be with javascript. Could you help me with that?

Comment: `$('input.spinner').on('change', function(){` do you know what this does? If you don't read up on `jQuery`. If you do, validate that this works. You need an input with the `spinner` class.

Comment: would I be off base to say my input is `value="{{ product.quantity }}"` in this line of code: `<input class="spinner" value="{{ product.quantity }}" style="width:30px">` and my class is spinner here as well?

Comment: @Glubus I made some improvements but as far as making this work with my database I'm really stuck at. Could you provide me with some helpful hints/links if you know of them, or have the time/ability to help me out further?

Comment: When the spinner change you make an ajax request on url: '{{ path('product_showCart') }}', ... You make on ajax request on the show cart action really ?? Not on an action saving the quantity ??